# Is the "continuous on its domain" definition enough?

Tags: functions, continuity, definition

Everybody knows the definition of "being continuous on a point" and it's defined well.

But the definition "A function $f$ is said to be 'continuous' if it is continuous at every point of its domain" is not adequate I think.

For example, let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

This function is continuous on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ which is also its domain. Then, is this function continuous?

It bothers me to claim that this function is continuous. Why would we define such a function as continuous? What happened to "drawing the graph without raising your hand"?

Comment: The "draw it without raising your hand" description isn't very accurate.  I would regard $f(x)=1/x$ as certainly continuous on its domain [which happens to be disconnected, hence the need to lift your pencil].

Comment: Yes, but are you okay with that? I mean as we "choose" what continuity is, as we determine its definition; is this a good way to define it? Does this reflect reality? There is a infinite jump at x=0 on the function I have mentioned. If a definiton makes this function continuous, I wouldn't choose it as a definition.

Comment: But you can't actually “make the jump” across $x=0$, since that point not in the domain! If you stand at any point $a$ in the domain, i.e., at any point $a \ne 0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an interval around $a$ where the function's values $f(x)=1/x$ deviate from $f(a)$ by less than $\epsilon$, and that's the definition of continuity which has turned out to be useful. In the language of nonstandard analysis, $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff an infinitesimally small change to the input (from $a$ to $a+da$) leads to an infinitesimally small change of the output.

Comment: If you extend the domain to all of $\mathbf{R}$ by assigning some value $f(0)$ by hand, then of course $f$ becomes a discontinuous function, but that's a different question.

Answer (score -1):

The primitive notion of continuity is that which only concerns a single point. We then can say "continuous over/on $S$" to mean "continuous for all points in $S$"*

What "continuous" means without qualification is ambiguous, although usually clear from context. Often times it will mean "continuous on its domain" simply because that's a sufficient analytical property to consider a function "nicely behaved" in order to prove further theorems.

What you've noted is that in the secondary school context, "continuous" does *not* mean "continuous on its domain," because mathematics at this level has yet to fully distinguish the descriptive and computational interpretations, and endeavors to retain the idea that you can plug a real number into a function even if that number is not in its domain (though of course, not necessarily resulting in any sense). As a reflection of this, in this context "continuous" means "continuous on the reals." $1/x$ is *not* continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, in line with this intuition.

*NB: formally, for points on the boundary of a set a function need only be continuous from the interior

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.  But I don't think this is what I was asking for. But what I got here is that we can make a definiton like "A function is continuous if it is continue at every point in R" . Yes, this solves my problem but causes some other problems. Like, functions with a domain [-5,5] will be counted as discontinuous functions. Even if they are continuous on their domains, they are not defined and so not continuous on R.

Comment: @máthēma Perhaps an illustrative example from analysis of why continuity on domain is sufficient would be good. I don't have much background in analysis, so I might have to get back to you on that, but the intuition here is going to be that being continuous on each continuous part of the domain is good enough, and reasoning can be applied "piecewise"